# Swipeable modal (to close) in react native

Tags: react-native

I work with Expo.

I'm building a modal on the right of the screen, to display components.

It should appear on a button click, and close on swipe.
I made a lot of researches but I can't find what I need to use.

I'm a React developper but I am new to react native. I'm looking for "gestures" but I'm not sure I can use it to achieve what I want.

Any idea about what I should dig into ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package to have that nice feature: react-native-swipe-gestures

you just need to wrap your modal with this package :

```
import GestureRecognizer from 'react-native-swipe-gestures';
    <GestureRecognizer
      style={{flex: 1}}
      onSwipeUp={ () => this.setModalVisible(true) }
      onSwipeDown={ () => this.setModalVisible(false) }
    >
      <Modal 
        animationType="slide"
        presentationStyle="formSheet"
        visible={ modalVisible }
      >
        <Text>Swipe Down Please</Text>
      </Modal>
      <Text>Swipe Up Please</Text>
    </GestureRecognizer>
```